# <Mac> TimeMachine backup keep prompting fail message

Tags: macos, mac, backup, nas, time-machine

I have setup time machine on my mac to backup periodically to may NAS. Having given a quota to the disk space allocated to the backup, I have observed that there are messages prompting periodically that the space is full.

[image: Backup_Failed]

[image: Time_Machine_Setting]

[image: Attempt_To_Backup]

I am just wondering if it is supposed to delete the old backups itself to complete the new backup when it runs out of space? If so why is it prompting such message? Is it just temporary and I need to wait till old backups expire?

Just want to confirm that I have not mis-configured anything, thank you very much.

==================================================

<Update (22 Aug 2020)>

The backup was completed after excluding the backup from the TimeMachine backup.

[image: Backup_Completed]

For Parallels Desktop, if not modified, by default the VM file would be in your user's folder
/Users//Parallels/Windows 10.pvm

[image: Exclude_VM]

You can confirm the change in the Parallel VM's setting.

[image: Parallel_VM_Setting]

Comment: The first backup seems to have needed 640GB. Does it say how big a subsequent backup will be as it starts?

Comment: Per the last backup attempt I see, it its backing up 443GB of data. It displays "Backed up xxGB of 443.02GB -- Freeing space", and failed the backup at the end. Not sure if this means it attempted to free space but failed.

Comment: It really looks like it just needs more room to work in, if it's trying to backup 450GB on the second attempt. Do you have large files with small changes - VM files etc can do that. Either remove them from the list of files to backup, or give it maybe 1 or 1.5TB to work in.

Comment: Hi @Tetsujin your are right, it is probably the VM file causing the problem. The backup completed after I have excluded the VM file. I guess the mechanism is to backup any delta changes, and that the VM file alone will change everytime it is launched, and blocks the backup considering its large single file size (it needs to gurantee all file changes are recorded).